# Access to calendar from gwt

Tags: api, gwt, mobile, calendar

Is there a way to write in the standard calendar from the smartphone from my gwt application.

Which that I can make a new entry in the calendar from the gwt application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a native application that you GWT application is running inside, then the easiest way would be to expose a native class to GWT via javascript injection.

For example with Android, your GWT application would run inside a WebView with a Browser instance. This browser can provide methods to you GWT application like this:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new GwtJavaJSImpl(), "injected");
```

The methods in `GwtJavaJSImpl` would then be accessible from GWT by calling the JavaScript method `injected.methodXxx()` like this:

```
public native void callInjectedMethodXxx() /*-{
    $injected.methodXxx()
}-*/;
```

---

If you don't have a native application on your smartphone, you could generate a calendar file (e.g. `event.ics`) which you then could let the smartphone download. That file would then be automatically added to the device's calendar.